# Why does this C maze solving algorithm give an unexpected result?

Tags: c

I have created a maze-solving algorithm like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
// Maze size
#define N 6

//define boolean
#ifndef MYBOOLEAN_H
#define MYBOOLEAN_H

#define false 0
#define true 1
typedef int bool;
#endif

int startX = 0;
int startY = 0;

//function prototype
bool solveMazeUtil(char maze[N][N], int x, int y, char sol[N][N]);

int main()
{
    char maze[N][N] = {{'.','#','#','#','#','#'},
                       {'.','.','.','.','.','#'},
                       {'#','.','#','#','#','#'},
                       {'#','.','#','#','#','#'},
                       {'.','.','.','#','.','G'},
                       {'#','#','.','.','.','#'}};
 
    mazeGo(maze);
    return 0;
}

//print the solution
void printSolution(char sol[N][N])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            printf(" %c ", sol[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
 
//checking if in correct path
bool isSafe(char maze[N][N], int x, int y)
{
    // if not, return false
    if (x >= 0 && x < N && y >= 0 && y < N && maze[x][y] == '.')
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
 
bool mazeGo(char maze[N][N])
{
    char sol[N][N] = {{'#','#','#','#','#','#'},
                      {'#','#','#','#','#','#'},
                      {'#','#','#','#','#','#'},
                      {'#','#','#','#','#','#'},
                      {'#','#','#','#','#','#'},
                      {'#','#','#','#','#','#'}};
 
    if (solveMazeUtil(maze, startX, startY, sol) == false) {
        printf("No solution");
        return false;
    }
 
    printSolution(sol);
    return true;
}
 
//actual maze solving
bool solveMazeUtil(char maze[N][N], int x, int y, char sol[N][N])
{
    // if (x, y) is goal return true
    if (maze[x][y] == 'G') {
        sol[x][y] = '+';
        return true;
    }
 
    // Check if maze[x][y] is valid
    if (isSafe(maze, x, y) == true) {
        // mark x, y
        sol[x][y] = '+';
        maze[x][y] = '#'; 
        //try move right
        if (solveMazeUtil(maze, x + 1, y, sol) == '.')
            sol[x+1][y] = '+';
            maze[x+1][y] = '#'; 
            return true;
        //try move down
        if (solveMazeUtil(maze, x, y + 1, sol) == '.')
            sol[x][y+1] = '+';
            maze[x][y+1] = '#';  
            return true;
        //try move left
        if (solveMazeUtil(maze, x - 1, y, sol) == '.')
            sol[x-1][y] = '+';
            maze[x-1][y] = '#'; 
            return true;
        //try move up
        if (solveMazeUtil(maze, x, y - 1, sol) == '.')
            sol[x][y-1] = '+';
            maze[x][y-1] = '#'; 
            return true;    
        // If none of the above movements work then unmark x, y
        sol[x][y] = '#';
        maze[x][y] = '.'; 
    }
    return false;
}
```

Which should start from (0,0) and end at G, and I'm expecting an output of

```
 +  #  #  #  #  # 
 +  +  #  #  #  # 
 #  +  #  #  #  # 
 #  +  #  #  #  # 
 #  +  +  #  +  + 
 #  #  +  +  +  #
```

But getting a result of

```
 +  #  #  #  #  # 
 +  #  #  #  #  # 
 #  #  #  #  #  # 
 #  #  #  #  #  # 
 #  #  #  #  #  # 
 #  #  #  #  #  #
```

I've tried to delete the 'return true' in line 101, which makes the program go further but is still not giving the expected output.

Can anyone help me determine where I made the mistake?

Comment: The compiler complains you don't have a declaration for `bool mazeGo(char maze[N][N])` but perhaps more serious is the one time you call `mazeGo(maze);` you ignore its return value. Time to deploy the debugger.

Comment: it doesn't look like you're checking if maze[x+1][y] and the other adjacent squares are safe with your isSafe function, so you're probably looking at squares you don't intend to or out of bounds

Comment: @SashaKondrashov I wondered that first, but the bounds are checked in the recursion. Of greater concern though, is that the recursive `solveMazeUtil` does `if (maze[x][y] == 'G') { sol[x][y] = '+'; return true; }` **before** calling `isSafe(maze, x, y)`.

Comment: So `isSafe(maze, x, y)` should be called right at the start of the function `solveMazeUtil`.

Comment: Note that in `solveMazeUntil`, every `if (solveMazeUtil ...` statement is followed by misleading indentation (raise your warning levels, i.e., `-Wmisleading-indentation`). Only the first line following these statements is part of the block. The second assignment and return statement belong to the surrounding block. This will create unexpected results, regardless of your intended algorithm.

Comment: @Weather Vane  I just tried that but it printed the same result.

Comment: Me too. I tried it, so it's time for the debugger. Aside: you can `#include <stdbool.h>` so that you don't have to re-invent it.

Comment: How do you expect comparisons such as this ... `solveMazeUtil(maze, x + 1, y, sol) == '.'` ... to serve your purpose?  `solveMazeUtil` *never* returns `'.'`.

Comment: Additionally, your indentation suggests an intended logical structure different from the actual logical structure.  You need to deploy some more curly braces.

Comment: In fact, you need to rethink the logic of `solveMazeUtil()`.  You're performing excess marking.  Though perhaps that turns out simply to be be redundant.

Comment: You are calling `isSafe` too late. You have already accessed a potentially unsafe location at that point.

Comment: @JohnBollinger has the correct idea I think, the if statements in solveMazeUtil badly need braces, and those comparisons to '.' don't make sense

Comment: Furthermore, as a matter of efficiency, you're exploring some false paths many times.  Once you traverse a particular point in the maze once, you should never need to revisit it -- if it is on a path to the goal then you will reach the goal during the first traversal.  If you don't reach the goal on the first traversal, then there's no reason to think that you would do on any subsequent traversal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple problems:

- the indentation in `solveMazeUtil` is misleading: use a block delimited by `{` and `}` when more than a single statement follows an `if`, `for`, `while` or `do` statement.
- these statements are actually useless once you have found a solution. Just return `true` if any of the recursive calls returns `true`.
- the recursive calls return `true` or `false`, comparing the return value to `'.'` is incorrect.
- avoid tautological statements and expressions such as `if (condition) return true; else return false;` or `if (isSafe(maze, x, y) == true)`

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Maze size
#define N 6

//define boolean
#ifndef MYBOOLEAN_H
#define MYBOOLEAN_H
#define false 0
#define true 1
typedef int bool;
#endif

//function prototype
bool solveMazeUtil(char maze[N][N], int x, int y, char sol[N][N]);
bool mazeGo(char maze[N][N], int startX, int startY);

int main() {
    char maze[N][N] = {{'.','#','#','#','#','#'},
                       {'.','.','.','.','.','#'},
                       {'#','.','#','#','#','#'},
                       {'#','.','#','#','#','#'},
                       {'.','.','.','#','.','G'},
                       {'#','#','.','.','.','#'}};

    mazeGo(maze, 0, 0);
    return 0;
}

//print the solution
void printSolution(char sol[N][N]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            printf(" %c ", sol[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

//checking if in correct path
bool isSafe(char maze[N][N], int x, int y) {
    // if not, return false
    return (x >= 0 && x < N && y >= 0 && y < N && maze[x][y] == '.');
}

bool mazeGo(char maze[N][N], int startX, int startY) {
    char sol[N][N] = {{'#','#','#','#','#','#'},
                      {'#','#','#','#','#','#'},
                      {'#','#','#','#','#','#'},
                      {'#','#','#','#','#','#'},
                      {'#','#','#','#','#','#'},
                      {'#','#','#','#','#','#'}};

    if (solveMazeUtil(maze, startX, startY, sol)) {
        printSolution(sol);
        return true;
    } else {
        printf("No solution");
        return false;
    }
}

//actual maze solving
bool solveMazeUtil(char maze[N][N], int x, int y, char sol[N][N]) {
    // if (x, y) is goal return true
    if (maze[x][y] == 'G') {
        sol[x][y] = '+';
        return true;
    }

    // Check if maze[x][y] is valid
    if (isSafe(maze, x, y)) {
        // mark x, y
        sol[x][y] = '+';
        maze[x][y] = '#';
        // try all four directions
        if (solveMazeUtil(maze, x + 1, y, sol)
        ||  solveMazeUtil(maze, x, y + 1, sol)
        ||  solveMazeUtil(maze, x - 1, y, sol)
        ||  solveMazeUtil(maze, x, y - 1, sol)) {
            return true;
        }
        // If none of the above movements work then unmark x, y
        sol[x][y] = '#';
        maze[x][y] = '.';
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your program, but the most significant ones are

1. `solveMazeUtil()` tests whether the current position is the goal position without first verifying that it is a valid ("safe") position.  This can produce a buffer overrun.
2. `solveMazeUtil()` returns either 0 or 1, never `'.'` (unless your execution character set is highly unusual).  Thus, it seems that the several appearances of expressions of the form

   > ```
   > solveMazeUtil(maze, x + 1, y, sol) == '.'
   > ```

   should instead be

   > ```
   > solveMazeUtil(maze, x + 1, y, sol) == true
   > ```

   .  Or simply

   > ```
   > solveMazeUtil(maze, x + 1, y, sol)
   > ```
3. You appear to have omitted braces around what appear intended to be multi-line `if` bodies.  For example, here:

   > ```
   >         if (solveMazeUtil(maze, x + 1, y, sol) == '.')
   >             sol[x+1][y] = '+';
   >             maze[x+1][y] = '#'; 
   >             return true;
   > ```

   ... only the `sol[x+1][y] = '+';` is guarded by the `if` statement.  The other two are executed unconditionally.  Probably you meant this:

   ```
           if (solveMazeUtil(maze, x + 1, y, sol) == '.') {
               sol[x+1][y] = '+';
               maze[x+1][y] = '#'; 
               return true;
           }
   ```

Note also, however, that you do not need to mark the solution or the maze after return from `solveMazeUtil()` prior to returning `true`.  They will have already been marked appropriately by the recursive call.

Moreover, note that when `solveMazeUtil()` visits a position, it tests *all* possible paths onward from that position.  Therefore, it is not necessary ever to test any additional paths through that position.  This is an efficiency consideration that doesn't much matter for small mazes, but which might become important for larger ones.